# d3.js link seperation in tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, line

what I'm trying to do is to have a gap in between the links of a d3.js tree layout in which the node name fits (See image).

http://s15.postimg.org/xn1eenxh7/linesplit.jpg

My graph looks similar to this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550
What I tried to change is the d.y in the projection.

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });
```

Which results in a change of both parent and child links. 
I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, but I don't get it right now.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to add the text with a `rect` or similar as a background that makes it appear as if the line is broken.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks. Mark suggested the same so the answer below. How can it be that it is so hard to split these? They are two separated lines anyway...

Answer (score 0):

To move the text, don't do it in the projection but in the transform the `g` container the text is in:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y - 50) + ")"; }) //<-- -50 moves it
```

To break the line, add a filled white rect into the container:

```
node.append("rect")
  .attr('width', 32)
  .attr('height',15)
  .attr('fill', 'white')
  .attr('y', -7.5);
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UWw2ZCbUAkMY2O7jarSk?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the answer. Yes I thought about a rect element behind my text. But there are two problems with that. This technique hides the area where the lines come together to the word. Its hidden behind the rect. Second problem is that the background in the file I'm working on has a gradient. a white or any other color rect wouldn't help. I need to really split the lines by the length of the text.